# Plot messing up with the data order

Tags: r

I have an object containing the data returned by the `likert` function from the `likert` package in R. It has the following data in it:

```
> facultyLikert
                                                    Item Strongly disagree Disagree Neither agree nor disagree    Agree Strongly agree
1                       3.1 Increased student engagement          0.000000 7.142857                   28.57143 57.14286       7.142857
2         3.2 Instructional time effectiveness increased          7.142857 0.000000                   28.57143 21.42857      42.857143
3                       3.3 Increased student confidence          0.000000 0.000000                   21.42857 57.14286      21.428571
4 3.4 Increased student performance in class assignments          0.000000 7.142857                   35.71429 50.00000       7.142857
5                 3.5 Increased learning of the students          0.000000 7.142857                   42.85714 42.85714       7.142857
6                   3.6 Added unique learning activities          0.000000 0.000000                   14.28571 57.14286      28.571429
```

It has the data in correct order, viz. 3.1, 3.2 etc.

But when I plot this data using the `plot` function, it messes up the ordering on some basis, shown in the attached plot. Is there any way to preserve the ordering as such?
[image]

Comment: Please make your question [reproducible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610). This means that besides including easy to paste data (preferably the output of `dput(data)`), you also need to include the code that you tried. This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution [here](https://github.com/jbryer/likert/blob/master/demo/likert.R)
Just need the replace the `plot(facultyLikert)` by `plot(facultyLikert, group.order=names(facultyData))`

This specifies the exact order of the y-axis

Where `facultyData` is the object containig the likert data.